# Can't install Flat Remix Theme in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, themes, gnome

I've tried creating a theme folder and putting the extracted files there but for some reason the theme isn't showing up in gnome tweaks. I've tried making a theme folder in home and in the local/share folder. Nothing seems to be working. I also dont have the option to enable user themes in gnome tweaks as I see in alot of tutorials.